# Searching for a user's posts in facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Searching for a user's posts in facebook groups. I am a newby on web programming, and I am trying to programatically get hold of all my posts in various groups. I am using plain HTTP queries, and also the graph api.
Using plain HTTP present a problem as I seem to have to phrase the query differently with some groups, and am even required to log in for some.
Using the graph api seems very limited since V2.8 only is allowed with new apps, and most of the functionality I need is only available in lower (V2.3) versions. And also I am NOT admin in any of the groups.

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is not allowed without their explicit, prior written content. You have to use the API for stuff like this - and if the API doesn’t give access to what you want, then that’s how it is. You can download all your user data from Facebook - you could try that, and see if your group posts are in there as well.

Comment: And how do you download all your data? I can download all my normal posts, but not those made to my groups.

Comment: Well if that is not included, then that is likely a deliberate decision by Facebook.